# How to use reactive global variable in global.R in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, global-variables

I have `ui.R`, `server.R`, `global.R` in shiny App.

I want to use a reactive global variable when I select `dataset` and press `actionButton`.

Example:

**ui.R**

```
fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Using global variable"),
  fluidRow(
      uiOutput("ui1"),
      uiOutput("ui2"),
      uiOutput("ui3")
    ),
  )
)
```

**server.R**

```
function(input, output) {

  output$ui1 <- renderUI({
     selectInput("dataset", "firstValue", choices = c("first", "second", "third")   
  })

  output$ui2 <- renderUI({
      actionButton("doIt", class="btn-primary", "change")
  })

  output$ui3 <- renderText({
      paste(catPath)
  })
}
```

**global.R**

```
catPath <<- paste(output$dataset, "/completed", sep="")
```

The result is `first/completed` on `ui3 renderText`, when I select `first` in `dataset`. and press the `actionButton`.

How can I complete this process?

Comment: Your code has extra and missing commas/parens.

Comment: I edited it. please check it.

Comment: In general `global.r` is used for functions, data, etc. that are not reactive. Reactive objects are created in the server.r

Comment: also curious what the purpsoe of global.R is here.

Comment: I understood. Is there any way to output the result I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @JohnPaul and @Lee88, your `catPath` probably belongs within `server.R`. Having said that, I'll keep it here for now (assuming you have other reasons for this in your MWE).

**`global.R`**:

```
catPath <- ""
```

I needed to set it to something in order to be reference-able later, otherwise the value used here should be meaningless (though it will be returned if no action taken).

**`ui.R`**:

I added a "stop?" action button so that you can "exit" your app and capture the value of `catPath` into the calling environment. Not required if you don't intend to intentionally exit the app.

```
fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Using global variable"),
  fluidRow(
    uiOutput("ui1"),
    uiOutput("ui2"),
    uiOutput("ui3"),
    actionButton("stopme", "Stop?")
  )
)
```

**`server.R`**:

I changed `output$ui3` to create the HTML object (not perform calculations), and then observe two events and act on them. Again, if you don't need the "stop?" button above, you probably don't need the second observe here. (If you do use it, note that the argument to `stopApp` is returned *invisibly* to the caller.)

```
function(input, output, session) {
  output$ui1 <- renderUI({
    selectInput("dataset", "firstValue", choices = c("first", "second", "third"))
  })
  output$ui2 <- renderUI({
    actionButton("doIt", class="btn-primary", "change")
  })
  output$ui3 <- renderUI({
    textInput("myinput", "catPath", "")
  })
  observeEvent(input$doIt, {
    catPath <<- paste(input$dataset, "/completed", sep = "")
    updateTextInput(session, inputId = "myinput", value = catPath)
  })
  observeEvent(input$stopme, { stopApp(catPath); })
}
```

Doing something like `newCatPath <- runApp("path/to/dir")`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Okay, could you answer one more question, if you don't mind?
I want to show directory lists on `selectInput`. `lists <- list.dirs(path = ".", full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE)` ,   `output$ui1 <- renderUI({
          selectInput("listSet", "lists", choices =lists ,selected = lists[1])   
      })` 
When I run my App, the selectInput is blank.
I know that `choices` is possible both in vector and list, what is the problem here?

Comment: When I replace `choices=c("first",...)` with `list.files()` in my code, it works correctly, so perhaps the problem is that `list.dirs()` is not returning anything (or `lists` is otherwise not correct). Try capturing the value of `lists` to a text box to confirm that it contains what you think it should.

Comment: I seem to have solved it. I'm very sorry, Can I ask the last question with the previous example? When I select `second` on `output$u1`, I want to show `second` directory lists on other `selectInput`. Is it possible? I'll accept your post.

Comment: This is possible using reactive expressions, as you've started. Perhaps set an `observeEvent(input$dataset, ...)` that adds another input field with the possible files listed. If you intend to continually created additional `select` widgets for each layer of directories, this will get very difficult to track. If you're talking only this second layer deep, then perhaps it would do better to statically define the two levels. Either way, I think it's getting more complex than I can really address right now.

Comment: Okay Thanks for your reply!